# How to disable MassTransit exception wrapping?

Tags: c#, masstransit, abp, fast-endpoints

**I apologize in advance for the long question.**

I am using [FastEndpoints](https://fast-endpoints.com/) in an [abp.io](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest) project. It's strange, not? Let's ignore the reasons behind and suppose we are forced to do that. Here's the sample codes:

Endpoint class in HttpApi project

```
public class Login(IMediator mediator) : Endpoint<LoginRequest, LoginResponse>
{
    private readonly IMediator _mediator = mediator;

    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("auth/login");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task<LoginResponse> ExecuteAsync(LoginRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // ******** exception A: from inside Endpoint itself *********
        // throw new BusinessException(AuthErrorCodes.Users.UserNotFound);

        var requestClient = _mediator.CreateRequestClient<LoginRequest>();
        var accepted = await requestClient.GetResponse<LoginResponse>(request, cancellationToken);
        return accepted.Message;
    }
}
```

Handler class in Application project

```
public interface ILoginHandler : IConsumer<LoginRequest> {} // this interface declared in Application.Contracts project
public class LoginHandler : ILoginHandler
{
    public LoginHandler() {}

    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<LoginRequest> context)
    {
        // logic
        // ******** exception B: from inside MassTransit consumer *********
        throw new BusinessException(AuthErrorCodes.Users.UserNotFound);
        // logic
    }
}
```

**The problem:** When I added FastEndpoints I found that default abp [Exception Handling](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Exception-Handling) mechanism didn't work correctly. After checking `AbpExceptionHandlingMiddleware`'s [source code](https://github.com/nirzaf/abp/blob/efbbc7dfa55a390da8a0e06f30ea3d8a76a4b1eb/framework/src/Volo.Abp.AspNetCore/Volo/Abp/AspNetCore/ExceptionHandling/AbpExceptionHandlingMiddleware.cs#L45) , I noticed that the`HttpContext` only handles exception when it has an item with "_AbpActionInfo" key in its [`Items`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8abaf0fb1bd5695bff2637c80cc5dae04c5b2ac2/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/HttpContext.cs#L52C69-L52C69) collection. To overcome this issue, I wrote a PreProcessor class:

```
public class HttpContextItemsModifier : IGlobalPreProcessor
{
    public Task PreProcessAsync(IPreProcessorContext ctx, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        ctx.HttpContext.Items["_AbpActionInfo"] = new AbpActionInfoInHttpContext { IsObjectResult = true };
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And configured FastEndpoint this way:

```
app.UseFastEndpoints(c =>
{
    c.Endpoints.Configurator = ep =>
    {
        ep.PreProcessor<HttpContextItemsModifier>(Order.Before);
    };
    // otehr configurations
});
```

With above changes, the problem fixed for only exceptions those thrown directly from FastEndpoints's `Endpoint` classes(A exception marked above). But the problem still exists for exceptions thrown from MassTransit `Consume` methods(B exception). Why? It's because MassTransit consumer wraps B exception into a MassTransit.RequestException class. Adding a try catch block and throw InnerException(BusinessException here), magically solves the problem:

```
public override async Task<LoginResponse> ExecuteAsync(LoginRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // ******** exception A: from inside Endpoint itself *********
    // throw new BusinessException(AuthErrorCodes.Users.UserNotFound);
    
    try
    {
        var requestClient = _mediator.CreateRequestClient<LoginRequest>();
        var accepted = await requestClient.GetResponse<LoginResponse>(request, /*Callback,*/ cancellationToken);

        return accepted.Message;
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex.InnerException;
    }
}
```

**The Question:** But I'm looking for a way to force MassTransit to not wrap exceptions, and throw them in a bare manner

Comment: You can't unless the low level library does a THROW.  Once an exception is caught it cannot be caught again without the THROW.  It wasn't magic that fixed the issue.  It was the throw that fixed the issue.

Comment: @jdweng Yes I know all you said, and of course it wasn't magic. You're right. The MassTransit must do that and I'm EXACTLY looking for a way to confgiure it to not wrap abp `BusinessException` exceptions into a MassTransit `RequestException` instance so I don't have to unwrap InnerException everywhere

Comment: You are sending an HTTP Request and getting Back an HTTP Response.  The HTTP Body contains a serialized class.  If you look at the FastEndpoints the classes are MyRequest and MyResponse.  The code is based on a HTTP Controller.  The exception is coming from the Controller base class in the library.  You code is inheriting the library methods.